# How to Add to cart in BigCommerce manually?

Tags: reactjs, bigcommerce

I'm using stencil theme in BigCommerce, we have a page that is created using React so what I'm doing is storing the selected options in Redux states:

```
color: {
  id: 792167289,
  label: "Color",
  image: {...}
}
```

I also computed the item price manually based on selected options. How can I add the item (item and it's selected options, price, quantity) in the cart?

**UPDATE**

I'm able to add to cart, but baseAmount and cartAmount does not work. The item price that gets added to the cart, is the one that is is set in BC backend.

```
 const res = await axios({
    url: "/api/storefront/carts",
    method: "post",
    data: {
      lineItems: [
        {
          quantity: 1,
          productId: 59,
          baseAmount: 123,
          cartAmount: 123,
          optionSelections: [{ optionId: 110, optionValue: 1000 }],
        },
      ],
    },
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });
```

Also for the optionValue (swatch) do you pass the selected option id?

```
color: {
  id: 792167289, // <-- this one
  label: "Red",
  image: {...}
}
```

so something like:

```
optionSelections: [{ optionId: 110, optionValue: 792167289 }]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want to use the [Storefront Cart Items API](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/6b15c26ac7d24-add-cart-line-items) for this, using optionSelections for your relevant modifier options.

I don't think this will be a direct answer, but will hopefully send you in the right direction.

Comment: it works but how can I manually add the item price? because I manually computed it, please check my update.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a custom price for products with the storefront API. The Storefront API can only be used to perform functions which a user could take normally on the site.

To set a custom price, you will need to use the [Cart Management API](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/81dc643c60052-update-cart-line-item). This will require a separate server to handle the requests, as these cannot be performed on a BigCommerce storefront.

If this does not work for you, you will need to set up rules to ensure that when the options are selected, the price is updated accordingly within BigCommerce.